# Learn the matrix function of a sort of bilinear form

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, non-linear-regression

I am thinking to the problem of doing regression on a scalar function f:R^n->R, where I have a set of training samples (x1,y1),...,(xN,yN), with yi = f(xi).

I know I could in principle apply any neural network architecture to do regression on this function, however I want to exploit a property I know about it to design the network.

Precisely, I know that f(x)= x^TA(x)x$ for a nxn matrix valued function A(x) which I don't know clearly, but I know is symmetric and positive definite.

I think that since I know this structure of the function, it is not an efficient approach to apply a "standard" architecture to this problem. This problem in fact looks like the one of finding and approximation of a metric on R^n.

Since A(x) is symmetric positive definite, I thought to rewrite it as A(x) = B(x)^TB(x) for an unknown matrix valued function B(x). Thus, the function f(x) rewrites in a much simpler way: f(x) = |B(x)x|^2, where the only unknown is the matrix function B(x).

Now, is there some known architecture which is well suited for this context?

Generating the training data with B(x) constant, I have solved the problem very easily defining a weight to be optimized and it works very well. However if the matrix B(x)  is x-dependent I am not completely sure on how to proceed.

Up to now I have implemented a NN which goes from R^n to R^{n^2}, where the output is reshaped into the nxn matrix B(x) to learn. However, this works well just for simple B(x)s and to me it is still not clear why.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the expression `f(x) = |B(x)x|^2` in tensorflow and solve for B via standard gradient descent minimization. Tensorflow can minimize anything you can write in tensorflow.

Comment: For sure it can,  but B(x) is not a function with a known expression, it is an "arbitrary" matrix function. This means that I first need to express it in some way, for example with a neural network, or even as some other expansion..or am I missing something?